# Use $match on fields from two separate collections in an aggregate query mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregate query where I join 3 collections. I'd like to filter the search based on fields from two of those collections. The problem is, I'm only able to use $match on the initial collection that mongoose initialized with.

Here's the query:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'blurts',
            localField: 'followee',
            foreignField: 'author.id',
            as: 'followerBlurts'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$followerBlurts'
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'followee',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'usertbl'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$usertbl'
    },
    {
        $match: {
            'follower': { $eq: req.user._id },
            //'blurtDate': { $gte: qryDateFrom, $lte: qryDateTo }
        }
    },
    {
        $sample: { 'size': 42 }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: '$followerBlurts._id',
            name: '$usertbl.name',
            smImg: '$usertbl.smImg',
            text: '$followerBlurts.text',
            vote: '$followerBlurts.vote',
            blurtDate: '$followerBlurts.blurtDate',
            blurtImg: '$followerBlurts.blurtImg'
        }
    }
];

keystone.list('Follow').model.aggregate(pipeline)
.sort({blurtDate: -1})
.cursor().exec()
.toArray(function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        res.json(data);
    } else {
        console.log('Error getting following blurts --> ' + err);
    }
});
```

Within the pipeline, I can only use $match on the 'Follow' model. When I use $match on the 'Blurt' model, it simply ignores the condition (you can see where I tried to include it in the commented line under $match).

What's perplexing is that I can utilize this field in the .sort method, but not in the $match conditions.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `followerBlurts.blurtDate`

Comment: @Bajal Wow really that actually worked. I tried it with the $ prefix ($followerBlurts) and got an obvious error, and didn't think I could reference it without the prefix. I find it strange that this works, but so far it seems like it is indeed working. Thanks. If you'd like you can post the answer and I'll mark as solution. Edit: I see now I was using the 'unwind' reference rather than the 'as' reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mongo *dot notation* to access elements of the collection that is being looked up via `$lookup`.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation

So, in this case `followerBlurts.blurtDate` should give you the value you are looking for.